# Female alien protagonist farms humans and crashes car in Britain

Tags: story-identification, aliens, food, love

I may have read this story in sci fi & fantasy mag. The story concerned a lower caste female alien surgically morphed and assigned to an earth food processing center in Britain. She was appalled that sheep were farmed. My memory fades about the part of the story on her home world, but it involves a male of higher caste she had a passionate interest in. Also I cannot quite remember the ending, but I believe it featured a car crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds awfully like Under the Skin, a novel by Michael Faber:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Under_the_Skin_(novel)

Comment: Thanks Kev. Totally random that I found this site from Google, with this story in mind, in the season that it's released as an indie flick. Not sure this is an approved comment though, but has anyone seen the film?

Comment: @mikeg you're welcome. I'd be careful about topic changes in the comments, we're not really a discussion site, or a forum. Also I wouldn't ask if anyone has seen the film as a question either :) There's a site specific chat room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/198/mos-eisley - so I'd go introduce yourself and then ask away in there.